# Space moves text to the new line

Tags: css

What happens without space: 
[image: http://i.imgur.com/KoClfup.png]
What happens with space: 
[image: http://i.imgur.com/BEnGeLM.png]
I want it to go to second line like in the second image.

I tried using word-wrap: break-word and disabling overflow: auto with no success.

```html
    <div style="overflow: auto;width: 100%; min-height: 41px; max-height: 100%;">
     <img src="" alt="BUFF" style="color:white;background:lime"> 
      <p style="margin: 0 1% 0 1%; ">
       fkdjhflgdfmlhfddmflhdfmlhfgmlmsdmqskdflmgdffdszrpooppomfllbcclkdjhflgdfmlhfddmflhdfmlhfgmlmsdmqskdflmgdffdszrpooppomfllbcclkdjhflgdfmlhfddmflhdfmlhfgmlmsdmqskdflmgdffdszrpooppomfllbcclkdjhflgdfmlhfddmflhdfmlhfgmlmsdmqskdflmgdffdszrpooppomfllbccl
      </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: `word-wrap: break-word` should be suffitient. What browsers have you tried? Could you supply a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or a code snippet?

Comment: Your snippet works if you put `word-wrap: break-word` in the style of the p element. Check for a typo in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try again but also add overflow: hidden on the paragraph. See my example below

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
p {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow: auto;width: 100%; min-height: 41px; max-height: 100%;">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/80x50" style="float: right;">
  <p style="margin: 0 1% 0 1%; ">
    htrhtrhtrhrthrthrthrthrthrthrthrthrthrthrthrthrthrthrthrthrthrthrthrthrthrtharsgrfesgrefresfgregrdsgfdsgrtesgre
  </p>
</div>
```